# How do I programmatically create views based on device orientation in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, user-interface

I want to create many view's programmatically and set their size based on the device orientation. This is how I am doing it now:

```
UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc] init];

if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation)) 
    view1.frame = CGRectMake (0, 0, 1024, 44);
else 
    view1.frame = CGRectMake (0, 0, 764, 44);

[self.view addSubview:view1];
```

But it is a pain to do this for each and every view. Also I have to duplicate the code I use in `- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration` method. Isn't there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Of Course you have.

the only thing you have to do is create a `BaseViewController` inherit from `UIViewController`

implement the methods to this base class, and all other `ViewController` you need inherit this `BaseViewController`

And you can also config `UINavigationItems`, `UIActivityIndicators` in this `BaseViewController`.

You have to adapt to the object oriented thinking :)

Answer (score 0):

Hey you dont have to do it. Set the AutoResizingMask for View, This is where you specify how diffent borders, height and width should reach to changes in parent views size.

Never try to change it manually. It will become complex.. Always make apple do it for you...